# how to remove part of strings and make a list for each line with values

Tags: r

My data looks like this

```
df <- structure(list(V = structure(c(4L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("132BALT_ 26,172BALT_ 27,107BALT_ 57,104BALT_ 59,137BALT_ 60,133BALT_ 61,103BALT_ 62,134BALT_ 63,177BALT_ 100,123BALT_ 133,184BALT_ 168,109BALT_ 197,103BALT_ 198,173BALT_ 202,157BALT_ 203,143BALT_ 266,62BALT_ 342,62BALT_ 354,92BALT_ 355,195BALT_ 368,164BALT_ 370,52BALT_ 468,74BALT_ 469,71BALT_ 484,98BALT_ 494,66BALT_ 502,63BALT_ 601,133BALT_ 622", 
"135A,510A,511A,60BALT_ 23,67BALT_ 24,70BALT_ 25,95BALT_ 26,122BALT_ 27,123BALT_ 27,109BALT_ 60", 
"25A,28BALT_ 55,31BALT_ 56,45BALT_ 57,43BALT_ 58,5BALT_ 59,47BALT_ 59,6BALT_ 60,69BALT_ 60,66BALT_ 61", 
"267BALT_ 361,786BALT_ 363,543BALT_ 392", "563BALT_ 202,983BALT_ 360", "8BALT_ 1,12BALT_ 35,10BALT_ 71,9BALT_ 154,51BALT_ 179", 
"91BALT_ 26,117BALT_ 27,117BALT_ 28,102BALT_ 29,47BALT_ 31,96BALT_ 63,78BALT_ 64,133BALT_ 65,117BALT_ 66,121BALT_ 66,112BALT_ 67,127BALT_ 100"
), class = "factor")), .Names = "V", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

I just show the first two lines of it

```
#1 267BALT_ 361,786BALT_ 363,543BALT_ 392
#2 563BALT_ 202,983BALT_ 360
#  .
#  .
```

what I want is to remove the first part until underline and keep the rest. so the output should look like

```
361,363,392
202,360
.
.
.
```

I want to have them as a list, I tried this

```
mylist <- lapply(str_extract_all(df$V, "(?<=[A-Z])\\d+"), as.numeric)
```

somewhere I am making a mistake, I would appreciate any help ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(stringr)
```

Option 1 = coerces into a list of a single element:

```
opt1 <- as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(df$V, "\\b[0-9]\\d+\\b")))

print(opt1)
#[1] 361 363 392 202 360  55  56  57  58  59  59  60  60  61  26  27  28  29  31  63  64
#[22]  65  66  66  67 100  35  71 154 179  23  24  25  26  27  27  60  26  27  57  59  60
#[43]  61  62  63 100 133 168 197 198 202 203 266 342 354 355 368 370 468 469 484 494 502
#[64] 601 622
```

Option 2 = coerces into a list with multiple elements:

```
opt2 <- lapply(str_extract_all(df$V, "\\b[0-9]\\d+\\b"), as.numeric)

print(opt2)
#[[1]]
#[1] 361 363 392
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 202 360
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 55 56 57 58 59 59 60 60 61
#
#[[4]]
#[1]  26  27  28  29  31  63  64  65  66  66  67 100
#
#[[5]]
#[1]  35  71 154 179
#
#[[6]]
#[1] 23 24 25 26 27 27 60
#
#[[7]]
#[1]  26  27  57  59  60  61  62  63 100 133 168 197 198 202 203 266 342 354 355 368 370
#[22] 468 469 484 494 502 601 622
```

Comment: much nicer than mine!

Comment: @Brandon S please explain what you did, so that I will understand it, also it give me a data frame with characters while I was clear in my question that i want list , and also look at my try, i want the elements to be numeric

Comment: @nik I just edited the answer to give you two list options with numeric values. as for `"\\b[0-9]\\d+\\b"`, this looks for all blocks within the text that only contain numeric values. the `\\d+` portion is actually overkill for your example, because it demands that all instances end with a numeric value (they'd have to anyways because we are only looking for numeric value blocks with the `[0-9]` portion). But since we are only keeping numeric values for this case, it is irrelevant. Here is a good resource: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/74603_76cd14d5983f47408fdf0b323550b846.html

Comment: @Brandon S thanks , I accept your answer, I don't know why people down vote my question!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The following uses `stringr` to manipulate the strings and `dplyr` to pipe the commands:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

mylist <- str_split(df$V, pattern = ",") %>% # Split the column in a list of vectors
    lapply(function(x) str_replace_all(x, "^(.*?)_", "") %>% # Removes anything before underscore
               str_trim("left") %>% # Removes the empty space before the number
               paste(collapse = ",")) # Collapses all the elements into a single vector
```

Comment: thanks thepule , could you please also add some information about it? i will appreciate it !

Comment: I have added some comments, let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: than you , I am more interested in ^(.*?)_", "" part,  I liked your answer although people down voted my question , i tried to appreciate your effort and help . thanks

Comment: No problem, I thought it was an interesting question.